# generating PDFs from html+javascript cakePHP 2.x

Tags: javascript, cakephp, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate pdf files in a cakePHP app, but so far get only html to be included in a file. The problem is that the main content of the page (calendar) is produced by the javascript which is completely ignored when generating a PDF. What is the best solution in this case?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: how about capturing the js output, sending it to the back-end and send it back to the front/display as a page that can be 'PDFed'?

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like wkhtmltopdf it should work as it contains the actual rendering code used in chrome.

There is a [plugin](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf) ready made that works out the box (after installing wkhtmltopdf)